# Composer and PSR-0 class autoloading with namespaces

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-0

Hello guys i have problem with autoloading my class with composer. On Linux all work perfect, but now my boss change env and set Windows.  All this work on linux but windows show newbie fatal error:

> Fatal error: Class 'AbstractController' not found in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\ikacFw\frontController.php on line 7

Common to see my composer.json and stucture for better picture on problem.

Stucture is :

```
frontController.php

-- vendor
----- Doctrine
----- Ikac
--------- Components
---------- Mvc
------------- Controller
```

Am trying to load all data from vendor directory.

**Composer.json**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "vendor": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Also new component i add manual. Like this :

```
$loader = require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
$loader->add('vendor', "Ikac");
```

Okay next when i try to call :

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

use Ikac\Mvc\Controller;


$a = new AbstractController();
```

I get error "not found".

My class AbstractController contain defined namespace but dont work again. Like test i do this:

```
    <?php
    //vendor/Ikac/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php

    namespace Ikac\Mvc\Controller;

    class AbstractController {

        function __construct() {
            echo __CLASS__;
        }
    }

    ?>
```

I do from cmd  composer **dump-autoload**, **install**, but dont work. All this perfect work on linux but here wont. Any idea how to fix this or where i do mistake.

Thanks guys!

**SLOVED:**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "vendor/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That "solution" states that "everything" is in the "vendor" directory. Which is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should do

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

use Ikac\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController;


$a = new AbstractController();
```

Comment: i already do that, u can see in post. When i add \Controller again i get the some error

Comment: No you missed the "AbstractController" last part in your use keyword. When you "use" a class, you have to specify the complete path.

Comment: When i add AbstractController keyword in the last part i get again ___
Fatal error: Class 'Ikac\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController' not found in___

Answer (score 0):

Your autoloading declaration is wrong.

You will NEVER ever need to include the vendor folder in any autoloading. The vendor folder will contain the autoloading for both all dependencies, and - if configured - for your own classes as well.

You can use Composer to create autoloading for your own classes. Just include the correct info. But from your current info I cannot deduct what would be correct.

Comment: Why do you think that's a bad statement? The same procedure used Simfony Framework. They also have a similar declaration  http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

Comment: Could you clarify where all your files involved are located? Where is `frontController.php`, and why is the content in the `vendor` folder there? I suppose it was put there by Composer - if this is the case, then the mentioned `composer.json` is wrong, as well as the attempt to call `$loader->add()`.

Comment: frontController.php is in the root dir. IDK this all i copy from linux and put on Windows and just here i have problem. On linux this work

Comment: Maybe it could be something related to permission? Can you check require is working?

Comment: Well, if you fetch the contents of that vendor directory by using Composer, then that stuff should be loaded automatically.